# python dictionary keys

Tags: python

I'm having a bit of a problem, don't even know if this is doable. I have a number of launchers that each have a interface defined with the expected inputs. The input values come as a dictionary. For example:

```
    dict_key = str(req_input[0]['name'])
    data = dict(dict_key = value)
```

Now req_input[0]['name'] is the key I would like to insert into the dictionary. Now I know what I'm doint here only creates a dictionary of the form {'dict_key' : value} but I was wondering if it is possible to create the dicionary as to be the form {'Actual value of dict_key' : value}

Regards,
Bogdan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this is simply using the dict literal `{}`:

```
data = {dict_key: value}
```

---

Other ways would be

```
data = dict({dict_key: value})
```

or

```
data = dict()
data[dict_key] = value
```

but these are longer so stay with the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is:

```
data = {}
data[req_input[0]['name']] = value
```

This way you can add multiple values to the same dictionary, or loop through req_input if you have multiple parameters there, i.e.:

```
data = {}
for input in req_input:
    data[input['name']] = value
```

Comment: As a side note, your key can be the actual value, as long as it is hashable: http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-hashable